# Remediating dynamic SQL into prepared statements

Tags: java, jdbc

I am starting a remediation of dynamic SQL statements to prevent SQL injection. I have a Web UI that uses more than 50 queries. I would like to write a Java class to build the set statements without knowing the primitive type ahead of time that way it could be more generic? I was hoping there was a class I could call that I do not know about? I have searched for answer but I am sure I am searching wrong. 
(i.e. prepStatement.setInt(1,999);  prepStatement.setString(2,”Sammy”) ; etc. )

Comment: Have you taken a look at a light-weight ORM like MyBatis.  See if that's got any features that you might be able to use? http://blog.mybatis.org/

Comment: What do you mean with remediating / remediation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to dynamically construct `PreparedStatement` objects at runtime, without knowing parameter types in those statements, probably so that you code can work with different tables?

From that I conclude that you need to find out the column data types and call appropriate `PreparedStatement.set*` methods.

Leaving aside how your code will receive table name, and parameter values for prepared statement, you can obtain column information by calling [`Connection.getMetaData().getColumns(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)). For every column, corresponding row in the `ResultSet` will contain a column `DATA_TYPE` with an `int` corresponding to one of the [`java.sql.Types`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html).

The [`DatabaseMetaData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) interface has a lot of useful methods for getting details about a particular database.